# python reading excel file incorrectly

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a python file that uses pandas to read from a data from a workbook and performs several operations on the data and writes it back to the same file under a separate sheet. In one of the loops in the program, I update a pointer value that is written to the excel file, where it is used to update the data values to be used in the next iteration. However, when python reads the next set of data values (which are generated using a reference formula), it does not recognize that the values have been updated between iterations and reads these values as 'nan'. How can I go about making sure that python reads the actual updated values rather than 'nan'?

I have provided a copy of the code snippet here:

```
file = 'NS.xlsx'
x1 = pd.ExcelFile(file)

df1 = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name = 'ReadtoPythonTemplate',skipfooter = 
12)
...operations...
book = load_workbook('NS.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('NS.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

print(iteration_index)
iteration_index += 1
update_index = iteration_index + 3 #update pointer in excel file to generate
#new data set in the file to be read in again in the next iteration.

df8 = pd.DataFrame({'Index':[update_index]})
df8.to_excel(writer,"ReadtoPythonTemplate",startrow = 5,startcol = 1,index = 
False)
writer.save()
file = []
```

Comment: I'm not a pandas user, and I didn't read your code carefully enough to understand it (or even to know whether you included enough to diagnose your problem accurately); but one misconception many people have is that Excel files somehow automatically get recalculated, or that formulas and the results of those formulas are always synchronized. If there are formulas involved, and the Excel **program** (that is, the big GUI from Microsoft) is *not* involved, then you will *not* have automatic recalculation.